# How do I hide ToolbarItemGroups in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I literally just started programming in Swift about 2 hours ago.  I have created a toolbar such as the one below (simplified by removing icons, buttons and repetitive items). I want to have multiple groups of tools and hide and show those groups.  The default would be say menu set A.  When the user selects a different menu set from the menu say menu set B then menu set B would show.  It doesn't appear that you can apply some sort of visibility property to the ToolbarItemGroup.  How can I accomplish this

```
import SwiftUI
 
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        Text("Content")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Menu(content: {
                    Text( "A" )
                    Text( "B" )
                                            }, label:{ Text( "Menu" )})
            }
            
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Label("a", systemImage: "questionmark")
                Label("aa", systemImage: "questionmark")
            }
            
            //  ------------- Other Tools -------------
            ToolbarItemGroup {
                Label( "B", systemImage: "questionmark" )
                Label( "BB", systemImage: "questionmark" )
            }
        }
    }
    .frame( height: 300 )
    .frame( width: 400 )
  }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

[image: Here's what the application shows]

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @ElTomato OK, TY!!  I did say I was very new.  I can't figure out what's wrong with it right now.  It looks VERY close to mine.  I'll be back when I do.

Comment: @ElTomato OK... wow that was harder then expected the error pointed to the first line of the first group but the error was in the 2nd and 3rd groups.  This code should work.  TY!

Comment: Since you don't have `NavigationStack` or `NavigationView`, the toolbar items won't appear.

Comment: @ElTomato All the toolbar items are showing up.

Comment: @ElTomato Also the NavigationView is that slide out on the left.  I don't want that I just want a toolbar at the top of my window at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `Bool` variables, I guess, like the following.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showToolbarA = true
    @State private var showToolbarB = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                Text("Content")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup {
                            Menu("Menu") {
                                Button("A") {
                                    showToolbarA = true
                                    showToolbarB = false
                                }
                                Button("B") {
                                    showToolbarA = false
                                    showToolbarB = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        if showToolbarA {
                            ToolbarItemGroup {
                                Label("a", systemImage: "questionmark")
                                Label("aa", systemImage: "questionmark")
                            }
                        }
                        if showToolbarB {
                            ToolbarItemGroup {
                                Label("B", systemImage: "questionmark" )
                                Label("BB", systemImage: "questionmark" )
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame( height: 300 )
            .frame( width: 400 )
        }
    }
}
```

In the following screenshot, I've selected Button A.

[image]

Comment: wow, I didn't even think about putting if statements outside the ToolbarItemGroup sections.  I could probably just use one variable for that.  Verifying that 'I'm" set.  TY so much.  I may have 4 toolbars.

Comment: That worked beautifully!!  I created enums for everything then I used a single variable to track the menu set and used the if statement to see if it is same name.  Worked very well.